# jquery animate hover and stop after certain time

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, clearinterval

Say for instance I have a animation executing on hover, naturally it's easy to stop on our callback function - I need to stop the animation after 1 second, would I do this with ClearInterval? My Actual function can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/7hujh/

```
$(elem).hover(function() {

  // animate

}, function () {

  // stop animating

});
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/7hujh/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just clear the interval after one second:

```
setTimeout(function() {clearInterval(vibrateIndex);}, 1000);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7hujh/1/)

Comment: thank you. I have more to learn still about the behavior of setInterval, and ClearInterval

Answer (score 1):

```
$(elem).hover(function() {

   $("#item").animate({property:value},interval).delay(1000).stop(0,0);

}, function () {

  // stop animating

});
```